# angularjs - how not to hard code urls in the templates

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs but have been working with django for some time.

I am used to the idea of writing the following in my templates:

```
<a href="{% url 'profile-page' user.pk %}">{{ user.name }}</a>
```

and the following being generated in the rendered html:

```
<a href="/profiles/33">Eamonn</a>
```

n.b. this profile-page url is defined in my url routing

This is very powerful as I can change the urls without having to change the templates.

I am loving angularjs but I am not too happy adding my urls into my templates and I am using a name instead of the url which feels like I am programming to an interface and not an implementation.  Also, if I specify a url two or three times in different templates it is not very DRY.

Is there any native way of doing this of something similar in angularjs?

Comment: If angularjs do not have nice utility functions for urls, then render them outside of template, and pass as variables

Comment: Have you looked into **[ngHref](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)** ? Also, please, keep in mind that Angular is a JS framework (which means it does it's stuff in the client, so it parses the templates **after** it reaches the client.

Comment: ExpertSystem: ng-href is js that runs client side.  I cannot see any difference to having ng-href run with a hard coded url or a named url except the named urls gives better flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `constant` in your app and then inject that into either the `$rootScope`, or controller that looks after the specific part of the page with the links.

Something like this:

```
app.constant('appURL', {
  login:             '/login'
  userProfilePrefix: '/profiles/'
});
```

Then your controller can request it as a dependency and put it on the scope (or you could put it on the `$rootScope` in `app.run(..)` :

```
app.controller('PageController', ['appURL', function($scope){

  $scope.appURL = appURL;
  $scope.userId = 33;

}]);
```

Finally, your HTML can use the following:

```
<a ng-href="{{appURL.userProfilePrefix + userId}}">Eamonn</a>
```

**NOTE** use ng-href where possible - all this does is means that if a user happens to click on a link before the interpolation has happened, they won't get redirected to `/{{appURL.userProfilePrefix + userId}}`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This looks like a good solution but I think will end up being a lot of code as the route names are not with the routes.  Thanks for the time on ng-href too!

Answer (score 0):

I found this library that does exactly what I want: https://github.com/airtonix/angular-named-routes

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a module to solve exactly this problem.

Here's the issue at AngularJS github:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7091#issuecomment-40742173

And here's the module repository:
https://github.com/betsol/angular-router

This module works on top of this library:
https://github.com/betsol/js-router

### Usage example

```
routerProvider
    .when('/user/:userId/post/:postId/comment/add', {
        name: 'user-post-comment-add',
        templateUrl: '/partials/user-post-comment-add.html',
        controller: 'UserPostCommentAddCtrl'
    })
;
```

```
<a href="{{ router.generate('user-post-comment-add', { userId: 100, postId: 500 }) }}">Add comment</a>
```